# Unable to update in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

While installing Google Chrome in my Ubuntu OS I'm getting the below error while updating.

[image: Please find the attachment for error]

Comment: Perhaps it is Ubuntu Software doing and update of the lists in the background? Give it a time and try again. If that fails, follow the answers in the question pointed out by @bodhi.zazen

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Still I'm getting same error

Comment: If you are still getting the same error, and you are sure another package manager is not running in the background, I suggest you reboot. Then, and only as a last resort, you can delete the lock file but I would again reboot after deleting the lock file before running any installation of software.

Answer (score -1):

You can delete the lock file with the following command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

You may also need to delete the lock file in the cache directory

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Comment: no use same error

Comment: deleting lock files should be used as a last resort and doing so can break ubuntu.

Comment: reboot the pc and try above code man....have fun

Comment: Shutting down ubuntu in the middle of updating or upgrading can also break ubuntu.